# Photon Pun 2 change position with mouse

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, multiplayer, photon

I think there is problem between Photon and mouse position. Because when I try to change position of object with keyboard it works successfully but when I try to change position with mouse it is not changing over the network. How can I change object position with mouse position over the network?

```
public class SpehreControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    PhotonView PV;
    GameObject sphere1;
    GameObject bt;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        PV = GetComponent<PhotonView>();
        sphere1 = GameObject.Find("Sphere 1");
        bt = GameObject.Find("BT_1");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

            if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && PV.IsMine)
            {
            PV.RPC("RPC_MoveOnline", RpcTarget.AllBuffered);
            }

    }



    [PunRPC]
    void RPC_MoveOnline()
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).x,
           Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).y, 0);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem in RPC function.
When you call it, every user receives only a call event with no params. It means, every user work with **his own** *Input.mousePosition* but not from the sender.

You can use params to fix this:

```
...
   PV.RPC("RPC_MoveOnline", RpcTarget.AllBuffered, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition));
...
[PunRPC]
void RPC_MoveOnline(Vector3 worldPosition)
{
    transform.position = new Vector3(worldPosition.x, worldPosition.y, 0);
}
```

But it's really not a very good way...

As I see, you need to synchronize the position of some objects for all users.
It's much easier to deal with *PhotonView* component (what your GO already has). Just drag and drop your GO **Transform** component to the *PhotonView* **Observed Components field** in unity inpector.

Using this, ALL changes with a transform of your local GO will automatically be synchronized for all players!
[more info here](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/v2/demos-and-tutorials/pun-basics-tutorial/player-networking#transform_synchronization)

Good luck!)

Comment: I am glad to help)

Comment: can I ask another question? how can I send dynamic array as you said like function's parameter with rpc? this is my array  `public int[] selectedDom` and I define it in the start function like this  `selectedDom = new int[28];
        for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++)
            selectedDom[i] = 28;` and I try to send it like this `private void RPC_Start(int[] selectedDomP)`. But this is working as code that you said.